# VueJS perform math function on specific set of inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently, I have a VueJS app where you can click a button to create a set of two inputs. These two inputs perform a simple math function on key up. These math functions work with one set of inputs. However, since I'm using document.getElementById to grab the inputs, it will only work on the first set of inputs. Is there any way I can uniquely identify each set of inputs so I can perform this math function individually?

Example:

```js
Vue.component('product', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <select>
        <option>Product One</option>
        <option>Product Two</option>
      </select>
      <input class="input" id="bags" @keyup="$emit('calculatevolume')" type="number" placeholder="Bags">
      <input class="input" id="volume" @keyup="$emit('calculatebags')" type="number" placeholder="Volume">
      <button @click="$emit('remove')">Delete</button>
    </div>
  `
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    index: 0,
    products: []
  },
  methods: {
    addProduct: function() {
      this.products.push(this.index);
      this.index++;
    },
    calculatevolume: function() {
      var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
      var bags = document.getElementById("bags");
      var volume = document.getElementById("volume");
      volume.value = bags.value * 25;
    },
    calculatebags: function() {
      var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
      var bags = document.getElementById("bags");
      var volume = document.getElementById("volume");
      bags.value = volume.value / 25;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button
         v-model="index"
         v-on:click="addProduct"
         placeholder="Add Product">Add Product</button>

  <div class="products">
    <div
         is="product"
         v-for="(product, index) in products"
         :id="index"
         :key="product"
         @remove="products.splice(index, 1)"
         @calculatevolume="calculatevolume"
         @calculatebags="calculatebags">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use v-model on your input fields instead?

Comment: I just read that in the documentation. Definitely looks like a step in the right  direction. I also don't think I'm supposed to grab elements by their id, let alone create the same variables twice for two different methods. That was more for testing purposes as I couldn't get global variables to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Vue, you generally do not want or need to be manipulating the DOM yourself in any way.

To that end, I moved the calculation of `bags` and `volume` into your component. Using `v-model`, they will always reflect the value in data. Additionally, I added watchers to their values so you could change the opposite number when they change.

```
Vue.component('product', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <select>
        <option>Product One</option>
        <option>Product Two</option>
      </select>
      <input class="input" id="bags" v-model="bags" type="number" placeholder="Bags">
      <input class="input" id="volume" v-model="volume" type="number" placeholder="Volume">
      <button @click="$emit('remove')">Delete</button>
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      bags: null,
      volume: null
    }
  },
  watch:{
    bags(newVal){
      this.volume = newVal * 25
    },
    volume(newVal){
      this.bags = newVal / 25
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    products: []
  },
  methods: {
    addProduct: function() {
      this.products.push(this.index);
    },
  }
})
```

And the new template

```
<div id="app">
  <button
         v-on:click="addProduct"
         placeholder="Add Product">Add Product</button>

  <div class="products">
    <div
         is="product"
         v-for="(product, index) in products"
         :id="index"
         :key="product"
         @remove="products.splice(index, 1)"
         >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/LyPBmZ?editors=1010).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I agree, it felt wrong to manipulate the DOM since that's the whole point of the directives. I'm still getting acquainted with Vue but your solution really did help for what I ended up using the select element for. Greatly appreciated.